# Given a name in sanskrit, how to find what to call the son or daughter of that person. What is the grammatical rule for forming such words?

Tags: sanskrit

Example:-
Kunti-- Kauntey

anjana-- aanjane

What are the rules

Comment: Check [this article](https://www.tititudorancea.com/z/patronymic_84.htm) out. There's a whole section about the Indian subcontinent, and a paragraph that talks about Sanskrit. I'm no expert in Sanskrit so can't verify or write a full answer.

Comment: Thanks for the article, but it only gives examples. It doesnt seem to explain the grammatical rules behind it.

Answer (score 1):

This phenomenon is called *guna* and *vṛddhi*. You can learn more here for example:

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vṛddhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%E1%B9%9Bddhi)